# Add text to the end of each list item in wp_list_categories

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for and not sure how to approach it.

I'm using `wp_list_categories` to obviously list terms of a taxonomy. I'd like to add some text to the end of each item.

Example being:

taxonomy_term some_new_text

instead of

taxonomy_term

Here's the basic `wp_list_categories` that I'm using:

```
<?php 
    wp_list_categories(array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'style' => 'list',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'title_li' => '',
        'number' => 25,
    ));
?>
```

Thanks

**Final code used to accomplish what I need**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'number' => 25,
    );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li>&nbsp;<a href="/locations/' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . ' ' . get_the_title() . '</a> |&nbsp;</li>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) (which returns an array of category objects rather than directly displaying them) instead of `wp_list_categories`, and loop through the results, outputting whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a custom walker for `wp_list_categories()`. That is a custom class extending `Walker_Category`. In that class you can change anything, including the list item ends.

#### Sample class

```
class Extended_Walker_Category extends Walker_Category
{
    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return;

        $output .= " |&nbsp;</li>\n";
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
wp_list_categories(
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
        'orderby'  => 'name',
        'style'    => 'list',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'title_li' => '',
        'number'   => 25,
        'walker'   => new Extended_Walker_Category
    )
);
```